# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cal'

Tags: python, django

I am a relatively new programmer and decided to start picking up python. I specifically was looking into the web development side of things. I was installed Django but I did so without being in a virtual env. I was still able to connect to the page. After following along with some tutorials I created a virtual env and then the server would no run and I would get a long error. It is posted in the pastebin link. It says missing module named 'cal' but I installed it with "pip install cal" but I still get this error. Any suggestions? Also, this is my first time using this website for help so I am also getting used to it.

https://pastebin.com/Gve79dLA

```
from django.urls import path

from. import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.home, name='home')

]

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

## Create your views here.

```
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

this is my urls.py and views.py

Comment: Well apparently in your urls you wrote `include('cal.urls')`, but that app does not exists.

Comment: "from." is one word try fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an app you installed via `pip`, you have to specify it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` parameter of your `settings.py` file.